# All rank-1 matrices have an SVD

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition, svd, rank-1-matrices

I have a rank-$1$ matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ and a vector $u$ in its image. I could prove that the columns of $A$ are multiples of a vector $u$, and that $A$ can be written as $A = \alpha u v^t$, with $u$ and $v$ unit vectors and $\alpha > 0$. I would now like to show that there exist two orthogonal matrices, $U \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ and $V \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times m}$, such that they have $u$ and $v$ as their first columns, respectively. The idea of this would be to prove that all rank-$1$ matrices have an SVD decomposition.

Would it be correct to take U and V to be the identity matrix with $u$ and $v$ in place of the first column?

If I have that $U$ and $V$, is it posible to apply those directly into $U \Sigma V^t$?

So far I know $\Sigma$ only has the value $\alpha^2$.

Comment: Suppose that $n = m = 2$, and $u = \pmatrix{1\\ 1}$, and you put it in the first column of the identity matrix to get $U = \pmatrix {1 & 0 \\ 1 & 1}$. Is that orthogonal? To put this differently, before you ask a question, it's polite to put in a little effort yourself.

Comment: Why not just use the theoretical concept of Gram-Schmidt to conclude that you can extend your single vector $u$ to a basis? Note that you should renormalize $\alpha,u,v$ such that $u,v$ are unit length. The rest of the $V$ basis that you get will be mapped to 0 via 0s in the $\Sigma$ matrix.

Comment: Of course that wouldn't be orthogonal. Sorry about that, @JohnHughes, I forgot to mention that both $u$ and $v$ were unit vectors.

AlexR, I am still trying to understand the SVD's inner working, but would it be correct to interpret that as that it would be rotating vectors in some direction and also "stretching" them by 0, so that the direction becomes irrelevant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $u$ is a unit vector, then it is often taken for granted that we could, if we wanted to, construct an orthonormal basis whose first vector is $u$; using these vectors as the columns of a matrix would produce an orthogonal matrix.

A non-concrete justification of this fact is that if $e_1,\dots,e_n$ denotes the standard basis, then $\{u,e_1,\dots,e_n\}$ is a spanning set of $\Bbb R^n$ (or $\Bbb C^n$).  It follows that we can find a linearly independent subset (which includes $u$) and which spans $\Bbb R^n$.  Applying the Gram Schmidt process to the basis $(u,e_{i_1},\dots,e_{i_{n-1}})$ produces an orthonormal basis whose first element is $u$.

There are more "practical" approaches, however.  For instance, in applications where we might want an orthogonal matrix whose first column is $u$, it is common to use the [Householder transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Householder_transformation) which maps $e_1$ to $u$.

Comment: Applying a *modified* G-S process produces an orthonormal basis. The steps in GS are "pick a new vector $v$; subtract from $v$ its orthogonal projection onto previously processed vectors; normalize the result and include it in the set of processed vectors." The modification is "after subtracting from v the orthogonal projection...if the result is zero, discard v; otherwise normalize it and include it in the set of processed vectors." Example: suppose $u = e_1$; as we process the next vector (again $e_1$!), the first step makes it zero, and we discard it, leaving us with $u, e_2, \ldots, e_n$.

Comment: @JohnHughes ah, that's an elegant way to handle that, certainly for this particular problem.

Comment: As someone who actually writes programs to do this all the time, I find that this "exceptional" case is actually commonplace, especially if by "if it's 0" you mean "if it's pretty near 0, so that normalizing might introduce errors."

Comment: @JohnHughes Fair enough